# multiple modal dialog boxes, unable to select the top most one

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a test and am running into unexpected issue managing a modal dialog box.

The user uploads a file in a modal dialog box and if the file already exist on the system another seperate modal dialog opens asking the user if they want to overwrite the existing file.

I am having difficulties in manipulating the buttons on this second dialog.

When I manage the first dialog I do the following, which works:

```
void switch_to_dialog_window(WebDriver driver){

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.d2l-dialog>div>iframe")));

}
```

The html when both dialogs are open looks like this:

```
<div class="d2l-dialog" style="top: 70px; width: 700px; height: 520px; left: 630px; z-index: 1002;">
    <div class="d2l-dialog-inner" style="height: 518px;">
       <iframe class="d2l-dialog-frame" src="/d2l/common/dialogs/file/main.d2l?ou=11346&af=MyComputer%2cOuFiles%2cSharedFiles%2cgooglefiledownloader%2coffice365filedownloader&am=1&fsc=1&asc=0&mfs=0&afid=0&uih=&area=MyComputer&f=&path=%2fcontent%2fenforced%2f11346-Gherkin_Cucumber%2f&d2l_body_type=2" name="d2l_c_10_968" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" style="width: 698px; height: 518px; overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d2l-dialog" style="top: 90px; width: 475px; height: 415px; left: 800px; z-index: 1004; display: block;">
    <div class="d2l-dialog-inner" style="height: 413px;">
       <iframe class="d2l-dialog-frame" src="/d2l/lp/fileinput/11346/Duplicates?files=photo.jpg" name="d2l_c_1_182" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" style="width: 473px; height: 413px; overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to control the dialog which mentions duplicates.

I tried to modify the method for switch_to_dialog_window to be more specific (as a test to identify the first dialog box to control that):

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.d2l-dialog>div>iframe[src^='/d2l/common/dialogs/file/main.d2l']")));
```

This doesn't work though so i cant implement that way to manage the 2 dialogs.

I tried to switch to the default content and then switch back to the Dialog using the method 'switch_to_dialog_window' but that doesn't work either.  I tried just trying to access the button on the dialog box directly but that doesnt work:

```
public void confirm_duplicate() {



    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, '/d2l/lp/fileinput/11346/Duplicates')]"));

    //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>div>iframe[src^='/d2l/lp/fileinput/11346/Duplicates']")));
    try{
        //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>div>iframe[name^='d2l_c_1_']")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update")).click();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("could not click on the Update button on the top most dialog box");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I seem to be running around in circles with this one and is exhausting.  Can someone explain how to get control of this top most dialog box?

And also could you possibly teach me as to why the following expression isnt working:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.d2l-dialog>div>iframe[src^='/d2l/common/dialogs/file/main.d2l']")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Robot API can be used to get handle topmost modal box if there is an issue with switching to frame.

To use Robot API, give the following line of codes

```
Robot key = new Robot();
key.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
key.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Make sure that the control is already on the intended button. If the focus is on another button on the modal, then give 'tab' or other keyevent to get the control on the update button.

Comment: Thanks @neetigya I had hoped to avoid using this as a solution.  It would be preferable to have a solution that enables me directly access elements on the iframe however.  As a workaround this work though so thanks for that, I hadn't thought of using Robot.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a break of a couple of months from automation.  I happened to be doing some maintenance on my scripts and found the root cause of this problem.

The issue was not with my code, the code was fine just i forgot one crucial step. During the business process a second window was opened which required user input.  I used the code to switch to this popup window.:

```
public void get_window_ids(){

    //Get the handles for the main window and the popup window for the upload button
            try {

                Set<String> AllWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
                System.out.println(AllWindowHandles.size()+  " distinct windows: " + AllWindowHandles);
                window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
                System.out.println("\nwindow 1 is " + window1+"\n");
                window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
                System.out.println("\nwindow 2 is " + window2+"\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

public String getWindow1() {
    return window1;
}

public String getWindow2() {
    return window2;
}
```

When I switched to the window2 I forgot to switch back to the first window.  I just missed the fact that there was a popup window I forgot about.  So if you are using these modal popups remember to return control back to the main window.